# The word isolate—verb, or noun?

Tags: parts-of-speech

While studying I encounter the concept of a '[*language isolate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_isolate)' (pl. *isolates*). I would like to know if '*isolate*' is a verb or a noun when appearing after the word '*language*'.

As an example let's consider:

> "Korean is a language isolate."

I can deduce the following:

> "[noun] [verb] [determiner] [?] [?]"

According to the research I have conducted, such as on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isolate#English) it is either a verb or a noun.

Comment: There's an article in Wikipedia about language isolates:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_isolate  In that context, it's clearly a noun, and an idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context, "isolate" is a noun. The fact that the plural "isolates" exists is a good clue: verbs don't pluralize by adding *-s.* "Language isolate" is a technical term in linguistics for languages or language groups that are not considered to be demonstrably connected to larger language groups.

*Isolate* is also used as a adjective and as a verb. When used as a verb, the pronunciation is different: it ends in /eɪt/, while when used as a noun or adjective it ends in /ət/. A fair number of words ending in *-ate* can be used as nouns or adjectives or as verbs with the same difference in pronunciation.

Comment: I was confused and now I understand, thank you herisson for explaining this to me!